# Run tasks in parallel and concatenate the output

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, task-parallel-library

I'd like to fetch multiple data providers and they return they same structure of data, but with different data output.  At the end the output of the datasources needs to be appended so I can use the total result. To improve performance these datasources need to be called in parallel. I am now having this solution:

```
Task<List<Result>> dataSource1 = null;
Task<List<Result>> dataSource2 = null;
foreach (var dataSource in dataSourcesToBeFetched)
        {
            switch (dataSource)
            {
                case DataSource.DataSource1:
                    dataSource1 = DataSource1();
                    break;

                case DataSource.DataSource2:
                    dataSource2 =DataSource2();
                    break;
            }
        }
await Task.WhenAll(dataSource1, dataSource2);
var allData = dataSource1.Result.Append(dataSource2.Result)
```

But I am not happy with it. When adding more data sources, I need to append the new result to the list, which looks ugly. Besides that, I'd like to use switch expressions, but I am struggling with this.

Comment: `Task.WhenAll` will return all the results.

Comment: @Rogier Why do you use `Task.Run` for I/O operations?

Comment: @PeterCsala Good question. It is not needed indeed. Let me update the example.

Comment: A simple `var results=await Task.WhenAll(DataSource1(),DataSource2())` is enough. Since all async operatinos produce the same output, `results` will be an array containing the outputs of all async operations

Comment: You don't want to await `null`, the `dataSource1` (and the other) can be overwritten if the dataSourcesToBeFetched contains duplicates

Comment: @AluanHaddad have you tried compiling this? `fetch` is the original function which returns `Task<List<Result>>`. This needs to be awaited to get the list.

Comment: Good catch. Flattening needs to be done after `WhenAll`

Comment: @AluanHaddad if you check this in [sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgZgpghgLgrgJwgZwLRIMYHsEBNkA0uIA1AD4ACATAIwCwAUBQAwAEFNArANyMvs0ALLyZsOAOgAyASwB2ARxF8AzOyqsASijgAbGAG8AviIqrqrAMKt9jVnfZmAHOwBsrALIAKAJTXb9gIpOAB4KF2CZZBhgrWRdGAA+JIBtAF1WZCxEDBRWAF5rVgARWCgAZSyEHJoCYtKK7Ih1Y1Z/ALsANygEViQ4vWR89gBOV3EAdQALCFkAQR0dT0zG5HEyiB0IDBh3KFkAT1CQsIjpKJjtPSSEghPY+KTPVkgYDEn8hOeIV8mfb28RAFDG1WgxAmZwpFovcrp8SjBypVqj4QTYwe07BQAOxjABiCCwAFsYTBPLIIAB3VhQi79RJ/QH2YHojGstns9kghyuU7nElJOoIhpVJooll+cWBHFhcT4okksmU6lnaGXen/Rl2ZkcnW6tlcvWGzmSo2m9qMQxAA===) it needs a lot of type annotations too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All this code can be replaced with :

```
var results=await Task.WhenAll(DataSource1(),DataSource2());
```

The [Task.WhenAll< TResult>(Task< TResult>[])](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall?view=net-5.0#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_WhenAll__1_System_Threading_Tasks_Task___0____) method returns a `Task< TResult[]>` with the results of all async operations.

Once you have the results, you can merge them with `Enumerable.SelectMany` :

```
var flattened=results.SelectMany(r=>r).ToList();
```

While you can combine both operations, it's best to avoid it. This results in code that's hard to read, maintain and debug. During debugging, you'll often want to break after the `await` to check results for eg nulls or other unexpected values.

The tasks and flattening run on different threads, which makes debugging with the chained calls harder.

If you really need to, you can use `ContinueWith` after `WhenAll` to process the results in a threadpool thread before returning them:

```
var flatten=await Task.WhenAll(DataSource1(),DataSource2())
                      .ContinueWith(t=>t.Results.SelectMany(r=>r)
                                        .ToList());
```

**Update**

To filter the sources, a quick & dirty way would be to create a `Dictionary` that maps source IDs to methods and use LINQ's `Select` to pick them :

```
//In a field
Dictionary<DataSource,Func<Task<List<Result>>>> map=new (){
    [DataSource.Source1]=DataSource1,
    [DataSource.Source1]=DataSource2
};

//In the method
DataSource[] fetchSources=new DataSource[0];
var tasks=fetchSources.Select(s=>map[s]());
```

But that's little different from using a *function* to do the same job :

```
DataSource[] fetchSources=new DataSource[0];
var tasks=fetchSources.Select(s=>RunSource(s));
//or even 
//var tasks=fetchSources.Select(RunSource);
    
var results=await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
var flattened=results.SelectMany(r=>r).ToList();


public static Task<List<Result>> RunSource(DataSource source)
{
    return source switch {
            DataSource.Source1=> DataSource1(),
            DataSource.Source2=> DataSource2(),
            _=>throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(source))
    };
}
```

Comment: To flatten result you may use `(await Task.WhenAll(...)).SelectMany(x => x).ToList()`

Comment: @JL0PD better use `results.SelectMany()` instead. In this case chaining methods results in code that's hard to read and maintain. An async operation is more than a call to be chained, with different types of errors. during debugging, it's far more likely to want to break at or right after the `await` call than after the merge

Comment: I am looping through ```dataSourcesToBeFetched``` as not all dataSources needs to be fetched. Sometimes just one, something all of them. How would you implement that part?

Comment: @Rogier The way the question's code is written, it looks like you use the `switch` to assign to variables only. What is your *actual* problem? Whatever it is, there are probably a *lot* simpler ways to do it. If anything, you could use LINQ and `Where` to filter items, `Select` to return `Task<..>` objects and await them. OR, if you have an ETL problem, you could use the DataFlow classes and route/merge messages with `LinkTo` or `TransformManyBlock`, grouping blocks etc

Comment: @Rogier I added two examples for picking the sources to use - one with a dictionary, one with a picker function. You should use whatever is easier to work with in your case

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks, this is doing the job nicely!

Answer (score 1):

A problem in your code is, that if the `DataSource.DataSource1` is not present in the dataSourcesToBeFetched, you are awaiting a null task.

I would probably go for a collection of tasks to await.

Something like:

```
var dataSources = new List<Task<List<Result>>>();

// check if the DataSource1 is present in the dataSourcesToBeFetched
if(dataSourcesToBeFetched.Any(i => i == DataSource.DataSource1))
    dataSources.Add(DataSource1());

// check if the DataSource2 is present in the dataSourcesToBeFetched
if(dataSourcesToBeFetched.Any(i => i == DataSource.DataSource2))
    dataSources.Add(DataSource2());

// a list to hold all results
var allData = new List<Result>();

// if we need to fetch any, await all tasks.
if(dataSources.Count > 0)
{
    await Task.WhenAll(dataSources);

    // add the results to the list.
    foreach(var dataSource in dataSources)
        allData.AddRange(dataSource.Result);
}
```